# Simplest possible IAM Policy is Denied. Why?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-iam

Having trouble getting an IAM policy to work for my SQS queue, I tried the IAM Policy Simulator.  No matter how simple I make my policy, it always says it is denied.

The policy below is intended to allow any action on any SQS resource.  It is a policy that I am attaching to a specific user, which is why the Principal is not specified.

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
        "Action": "sqs:*",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:::*"
    }
  ]
}
```

When I try and run this in the policy simulator for a listQueues action, I get denied: Implicitly denied (no matching statments).  How could this statement possibly not match?

Here'a a screenshot of that being denied on the policy editor:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not the simplest possible IAM policy. This is:

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Action":  "*",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": "*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Are you clicking "Apply" at the bottom of the policy editor before you run the simulation?

Comment: You are correct.  Changing the Resource clause to what you have did fix the problem.  See my answer for details.

Comment: I'd add that you need an additional Principal:* if you will ever need to have a role with this type of policy attached assumed by another AWS service. It's not needed for the simplest of policy like the question is asking, but for STS to assume a role, it is. 

However, it's also strongly recommend that you do not use a wildcard in the Principal element in a role's trust policy unless you otherwise restrict access through a Condition element in the policy. Otherwise, any IAM user in any account can access the role.

Answer (score 4):

By default, the IAM Policy simulator sets the ARN of the resource you are simulating accessing to `*`.  For some reason, this is not matched by a Resource clause of `"Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:*"`

Once I expanded the resource part of the simulator (see screenshot below), and pasted in the ARN for a valid SQS resource, the policy matched.  See the bottom of the screenshot below.

Another thing that I found fixed the problem was what @Mark-B suggested. Changing the Resource clause to `"Resource": "*"`.  did match the Policy Simulator's default resource of `*` whereas `"Resource": "arn:aws:sqs:*:*:*"` did not.

[image]